# Custom layout magento

Tags: magento

I have sucesfully added a custom page layout in magento using this simple tutorial http://www.implementek.com/adding-new-page-layout-for-magento-cms-pages/

Which has worked fine and I can see the new layout in the backend of Magento. My question is how do add another? I cant seem to get magento to recognise the other new pages... How can I reference more pages in the xml file?

```
<cms>
<layouts>
<redirect>
<label>Woman Product Page</label>
<template>page/1column-woman.phtml</template>
</redirect>
</layouts>
</cms>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another one? For example:

```
<cms>
    <layouts>
        <redirect>
            <label>Woman Product Page</label>
            <template>page/1column-woman.phtml</template>
        </redirect>
        <another>
            <label>Man Product Page</label>
            <template>page/1column-man.phtml</template>
        </another>
    </layouts>
</cms>
```